# Testing RegEx against Null

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

When calling RegEx.prototype.test() on `null`, JS runtimes appear to convert `null` into its string form (`"null"`) and then test the regex against that. A few examples:

```
/[a-z]+/.test(null)
    true

/null/.test(null)
    true

/[0-9]+/.test(null)
    false

/nnull/.test(null)
    false
```

My questions are:

1. Why?
2. Is this correct behavior according to current specifications?

This behavior is horribly unintuitive. Since `null` conceptually represents the absence of any object, it conceptually makes sense that a RegEx test against it would fail, because there should be nothing to test against. It doesn't help that a lot of basic RegEx will succeed on testing against `"null"`.

I have confirmed this behavior in Node.js and Firefox Nightly.

Comment: `null` means there is nothing there, not empty, neither undefined. so why are you testing against null

Comment: @simsim - No, `var x; alert(x)` alerts the text "undefined". Whereas trying to `alert(x)` if x has not been declared (or created as a global via assignment) will result in a runtime error.

Comment: @nnnnnn, you are right, sorry for the wrong info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is as specified.

Per [§21.2.5.13 "RegExp.prototype.test( S )"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-regexp.prototype.test) in the 2015 version (6th Edition), one of the first few steps is to apply the "ToString" operation to the argument S, and use its result. [The "ToString" operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring) converts various non-string values to string values; `null`, in particular, is converted to `"null"`.

Answer (score 2):

[21.2.5.13 RegExp.prototype.test( S )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-regexp.prototype.test)

> The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let R be the this value.
> 2. If Type(R) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 3. Let string be ToString(S).
> 4. ReturnIfAbrupt(string).
> 5. Let match be RegExpExec(R, string).
> 6. ReturnIfAbrupt(match).
> 7. If match is not null, return true; else return false.

And look at the [ToString(S)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring) you will see null = "null" and you get what you see.